# How to create different Time frequency images from a data

Tags: image-processing, signal-analysis, python, wavelet, stft

I'm new to Python.
I have a time series in a CSV file that has about 5000 rows and 3 columns.

I have split the data into training and testing in ratio 70:30 respectively.

However, I have a problem on how I use time window containing 1024 data points in one sample and every sample is converted to a time-frequency image (STFT) with size of 224 × 224 x 3.

Comment: Hi and welcome here. I have trouble following your thoughts /needs. First of all what is "one sample" and how are you planing to to go from 1024 time samples to a STFT of 224x224?

Comment: Hi  @Irreducible, One sample  = 1024 data points. I have 1000 samples and wish to create STFT of sizes 224x224 from each sample. Hope this makes it clearer?